# Symfony 2 repeated field validation duplicated message

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, error-handling

I have this registration form in symfony 2.
The password field is a 'repeated' type:

```
$builder
...
->add('password', 'repeated', array( 
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'invalid_message' => 'The passwords must match.',
                    'required' => true,
                    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password:'),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password:'),
                    'constraints' => array(
                            new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'Password should not be blank.')),
                            new Assert\Length(array(
                                    'min' => 8,
                                    'max' => 40,
                                    'minMessage' => "Password must be at least {{ limit }} characters long.",
                                    'maxMessage' => "Password cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters.",
        )),
    )
))
...
```

In twig template just using form.password is not enough since no error message will be shown. I have to use form.password.first.

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
...
    {{ form_errors(form.password.first) }}
...
{% endif  %}
```

The result is:

```
The password must be at least 8 characters long.  <-- The default error message
Password must be at least 8 characters long.      <-- Mine
```

If I don't set minMessage or maxMessage the result is:

```
The password must be at least 8 characters long.  
This value is too short. It should have 8 characters or more. <-- Default minMessage message
```

How can I do for making it show only one error message? Of course i can intercept form errors in controller and manipulate it there, but i wanted a better solution.

Comment: Do you use `form_row` in your form's template ?

Comment: No, I am manually rendering them                                  `{{ form_widget(form.password.first, { 'attr': {'pattern': '.{8,}','title': 'Minimum 8 characters long'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.second, { 'attr': {'pattern': '.{8,}','title': 'Minimum 8 characters long'}}) }}` **and** for errors  `{{ form_errors(form.password.first) }}`

Comment: Basically the errors that the password field gives me is:   `["password"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["first"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(48) "The password must be at least 8 characters long."
      [1]=>
      string(44) "Password must be at least 8 characters long."
    }
  }`

Comment: @Carondimonio Did you solved this? I have the same issue..

Comment: same, that's bad there is still no fix for that !

Comment: Same, and still no fix :/

Answer (score 0):

Mb it's late, but I still see not much info on the same question. In symfony 4.4 this worked for me

```
$form->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'required' => true,
    'invalid_message' => 'your message',
    'first_options' => ['label' => 'Password'],
    'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
    'options' => ['error_bubbling' => true],
    //'error_bubbling' => false, default
    ...
]);
```